# Finding screen width and height dynamically in OpenGL GLUT program

Tags: opengl, glut

In my OpenGL program, in order to run it in fullscreen mode, I'm using the GLUT function glutGameModeString(const char *string).
 (where 'string' specifies the screen width,height,pixelDepth and refresh rate)
 To make it working in any system,i need to dynamically determine the screen width and screen height of the host system, prior to making the call to 'glutGameModeString' function.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are wrong, there are the following constants:

```
GLUT_SCREEN_HEIGHT
GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH
```

I've tested it, it works.

Comment: but these don't work after using glutFullScreen() :(

Comment: Im not sure but I think glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH/HEIGHT) should fix it

Comment: Adding the glutGet(…) COMMAND solved the incorrect Window Width and Height problem in my case. `glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH);` `glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_HEIGHT);` Reference: StackAttack’s answer to the question; 2018-11-09T02:03

Answer (score 1):

Just tested on Linux Mint 18

```
std::cout << "glut screen width(DEFUALT): " << GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH << std::endl;
std::cout << "glut screen height(DEFAULT): " << GLUT_SCREEN_HEIGHT << std::endl;
std::cout << "glut screen width: " << glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH) << std::endl;
std::cout << "glut screen height: " << glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_HEIGHT) << std::endl;
```

outputs:

```
glut screen width(DEFAULT): 200
glut screen height(DEFAULT): 201
glut screen width: 1366
glut screen height: 768
```

setting your window size to `glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH/HEIGHT);` will maximize your window, still has top bar and border.

Just calling `glutFullScreen();` after initializing your window will make it full screen with no borders or anything, no need for the above stuff of getting your screen size.